# SQLiteDatabase class cannot be resolved in coding IDE, how to set up it?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am exploring the source code of an App. There is SQLiteDatabase used in the source code.

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        private SQLiteDatabase db;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
```

I put the source code in my IntelliJ and Android Studio IDEs, but both of them cannot recognize this class. The `import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase` is also shown in grey color. I am totally new for writing Apps, is there anything to set up to use this class?

Answer (score 0):

The name of the class is `SQLiteDatabase` not `SQLiteDataBase` with a capital `B`. Hence the other is flagged as unrecognized and the import as unused.

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo here. I do use SQLiteDatabase in my code, but it shows "SQLiteDatabase cannot be resolved."